# bootstrap modal div across html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below bootstrap modal dialog div. There are 4 html pages in my web application . I want to have the same modal dialog in all these 4 html pages.
I do not want to repeat the code . I have a common js for this. What is the correct way to achieve this?.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Thanks.

Comment: May be you can have a placeholder in all your html files and using a js function injects the above html whereever it is required.

Comment: which backend are you use?

Comment: Concept should be you can define a modal in a separate file. append this file to a perticular `<div>` tag whenever needed using `jquery` is a better idea. @javaUser

Comment: save it into an exernal file and convert your pages to .php to include it into each page, or .shtml to do the same as a server side include

Comment: You either use ajax or server side code to include it.

Comment: It is a client side file then how to use ajax?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript library JQuery has a nice and easy to use wrapper for ajax-calls.
Put your modal in a seperate file and `$.get` it from your filesystem.

```
    $(function(){
        $.get('modal.html',function(html){ 
            $("#modal-placeholder").html(html);
        });
    });
```

If this is your only use of JQuery, you could instead use javascript's own ajax call.In my opinion it is not as easy to read or understand but it does the work just the same:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === OK) {
            var modalPlaceholder = document.getElementById("modal-placeholder");
            modalPlaceholder.innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'modal.html');
xhr.send(null);
```